# How can I run Remote Desktop Sharing on Ubuntu Bionic with Unity?

Tags: remote-desktop

When I try running the preferences for Desktop sharing from Unity control center, it fails with:

```
(unity-control-center:8681): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 19:53:26.258: Settings schema 'org.gnome.Vino' does not contain a key named 'enabled'
```

Running the command:

```
/usr/lib/vino/vino-server --sm-disable
```

starts the VINO server, but how do I set a password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, one needs to run `gnome-control-center sharing` and set the password there (no idea how to run this passwordless, which was previously possible, I think). The service cannot be enabled from there, but one can add a startup command via startup applications `/usr/lib/vino/vino-server --sm-disable`.

But this is clearly buggy under Unity.